# Can anyone explain to me this LabView simulation?

Tags: loops, labview

I'm currently learning LabView in college and I saw this simulated there on class notes. I've been absent the day this has been asked:

[image]
I asked my friends, but no one explained well. All they said: do not forget that when the user inputs a number to the control on front panel, he needs to press outside or enter to take effect.

Can anyone explain to me in detail the function of this program from logic design and user perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a while loop that is controlled by the "stop 2" button.  Within that outer while loop is a sequence structure that contains 3 frames.

Frame 1. A while loop that continuously samples the control named "x", adds five to the value of "x" and puts the result in the indicator named "x+y". If the user presses the stop button, the program will exit the while loop and move to the next frame for execution.

Frame 2. Pause for 10000 milliseconds.

Frame 3. After the pause, a local variable reads the value of the "x" control and writes it to an indicator named "x2"

This will repeat while the "stop 2" button is in a false state.